# What's the canonical way to serve JSON using Ocsigen?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

The [Ocsigen/Eliom tutorial](http://ocsigen.org/tutorial/application) starts with an example of an application that serves up "Hello, world!" as HTML:

```
open Eliom_content.Html5.D

let main_service =
  Eliom_registration.Html5.register_service
    ~path:["graff"]
    ~get_params:Eliom_parameter.unit
    (fun () () ->
      Lwt.return
         (html
           (head (title (pcdata "Page title")) [])
           (body [h1 [pcdata "Graffiti"]])))
```

How would one serve this as JSON instead? Specifically, how does one register a JSON service, and what library/combinators should be used to generate/serialize the JSON (js_of_ocaml?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do, but, about JSON, you can use "deriving" (cf. [Deriving_Json](http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/api/Deriving_Json)) to create a JSON type by using an OCaml type like this:

```
    type deriving_t = (string * string) deriving (Json)
```

This will create the JSON type corresponding to the OCaml type.

Here the way of using this type to communicate with the server (if you don't know server functions, here the [documentation](http://ocsigen.org/eliom/api/server/Eliom_pervasives) about it and about client values on server side):

```
    (* first you have to create a server function (this allowed the client to call a function from the server *)
    let json_call =
      server_function
        Json.t<deriving_t>
        (fun (a,b) ->
           Lwt.return (print_endline ("log on the server: "^a^b)))

    (* let say that distillery has already generate all the needed stuff (main_service, Foobar_app, etc..) *)
    let () =
      Foobar_app.register
        ~service:main_service
        (fun () () ->
           {unit{
             (* here I call my server function by using ocaml types directly, it will be automatically serialize *)
             ignore (%json_call ("hello", "world"))
           }};
           Lwt.return
             (Eliom_tools.F.html
                ~title:"foobar"
                ~css:[["css";"foobar.css"]]
                Html5.F.(body [
                   h2 [pcdata "Welcome from Eliom's distillery!"];
               ])))
```

If you want to use some **client/server communication**, you should take a look to Eliom_bus, Eliom_comet or Eliom_react.

(sorry, I can't make more than 2 links :) but you will find the documentation on the ocsigen.org website).

Hope that can help you.

Answer (score 6):

- If you want to communicate with a client side Eliom program, you do not need to serialize yourself your data to JSON. Serialization/Deserialization of any OCaml type is done automatically by Eliom. Just use OCaml services (or, simpler: server functions and call the function from your OCaml client side program).
- If you want to use your own JSON format, you need to have your own serialisation function to JSON (or for example to use some ocaml library like json-wheel to generate JSON). In that case, you can register your service using Eliom_registration.String instead of Eliom_registration.Html5. The handler function must return the JSON value as a string, and a the content-type.
- It is even possible to define yourself your own registration module, to be used instead of Eliom_registration.String. Thus, you can use an OCaml representation of the JSON value (and you don't call the serializer yourself). Have a look on how modules like Eliom_registration.String are implemented to know how to do that.

Comment: json-wheel is obsolete, use yojson instead